# how to select tail text with css selector

Tags: css, selector

I got serial of html basically like following, would like to use CSS selector to select the `(20 pages)` part, but couldn't figure out how to do this.

```
<a href="###" title="the 360 chapter" target="_blank">
  <span class="red">the 360 chapter</span> 
  (20 pages)
</a>
```

I have to mention that I am not styling the text, but using css selector for data collecting with programming. Hopefully this will not cause of misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

There is not selector for that tail text AFAIK.

You can differentiate the styling between the 2 by adding a default style to `<a>`:

```css
a {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="###" title="the 360 chapter" target="_blank">
  <span class="red">the 360 chapter</span> (20 pages)
</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, add some extra info in OQ, I would like to pick the content rather than styling them. Sorry for misleading. // any ideas?